# Poor recognition due to background noise using OpenEars on iOS

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, noise-reduction, pocketsphinx, openears

I'm using **OpenEars** in my app for performing the recognition of some words and sentences. I have followed the basic tutorial for the [offline speech recognition](http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/) and executed a porting in Swift. This is the setup procedure

```
self.openEarsEventsObserver = OEEventsObserver()
self.openEarsEventsObserver.delegate = self
let lmGenerator: OELanguageModelGenerator = OELanguageModelGenerator()
addWords()
let name = "LanguageModelFileStarSaver"
lmGenerator.generateLanguageModelFromArray(words, withFilesNamed: name, forAcousticModelAtPath: OEAcousticModel.pathToModel("AcousticModelEnglish"))
lmPath = lmGenerator.pathToSuccessfullyGeneratedLanguageModelWithRequestedName(name)
dicPath = lmGenerator.pathToSuccessfullyGeneratedDictionaryWithRequestedName(name)
```

The recognition works well in a quiet room for both single words and whole sentences ( I would say it has a 90% hit rate). However, when I tried in quiet pub with a light background noise the app had serious difficulties in recognising even just word. 
Is there any way to improve the speech recognition when there is background noise?

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/icaksama/iSphinx I hope can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If the background noise is more or less uniform (i.e. has a regular pattern), you can try [adaptation of the acoustic model](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt), otherwise it's an open problem sometimes referred to as the [*cocktail party effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect), which [can be part solved](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/537101/deep-learning-machine-solves-the-cocktail-party-problem/) using DNNs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting, works well for me.

```
try? OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().secondsOfSilenceToDetect = 2
OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().setSecondsOfSilence()
OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().vadThreshold = 3.5
OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().removingNoise = true
```

Or You can try [iSphinx](https://github.com/icaksama/iSphinx) library.